# How do I adjust the x-axis to start by 2000 and count by 1 each year in R?

Tags: r

[summary(df)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlQ4A.png)[My data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwNS6.png)

I have tried the following codes.

```
axis(3, at=seq(0,29,1))
axis(1, at=seq(0,29,1))
axis(3, at=seq(2000,2029,1))
```

I need the x axis to start at `2000` and end at `2029`.

```
plot(df, main="Measles Cases from 2000 to 2029" xlab="Year", ylab="Cases")
```

Comment: How do I add 2000 and increase by increment of 1 until 2029 in R

Comment: axis(1, at=seq(0,29,2000)) this is what I tried and it did not work. I tried changing the last argument to 1 it didn't work either

Comment: Please share your code, your data, and your attempts

Comment: > axis(3, at=seq(0,29,1))
> axis(1, at=seq(0,29,1))
> axis(3, at=seq(2000,2029,1))

Comment: Please use the **Edit** button to update your question with more details

Comment: updated it please see following changes

Comment: What are the content of `df`? Can you show the output of `head(df)` or `summary(df)`?

Comment: Do you need the summary(df) to change the x axis to start at 2000 instead of 5? I am confused on how to change the x axis. I think i have figured out the statistical part of this dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `summary(df)` output, `df` is a vector, not a dataframe.

You can simply plot it like this:

```
plot(2000:2029, df, main="Measles Cases from 2000 to 2029" xlab="Year", ylab="Cases")
```

To clarify, `plot` can be used as [`plot(x, y)`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.6.2/topics/plot), allowing you to specify both `x` and `y` values as two separate [vectors (of the same length).